# Unwanted Gap in HTML Email for Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, responsive

I'm making an HTML email that's responsive without using media queries. It works, but in Microsoft Outlook 2010, which a lot of our clients use, it shows a gap between the two tables. On every other device it does NOT show a gap. How can I remove the gap in Outlook?

[image]

Note: I need to use multiple tables so the email will be responsive. If I use another td instead, it won't be responsive.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .msoFix {
            mso-table-lspace: -1pt;
            mso-table-rspace: -1pt;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <div style="max-width:640px !important;">
                        <table class="msoFix" width="320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="290" bgcolor="454545" align="left" style="padding: 0px;"><br>Table 1</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="msoFix" width="320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="290" bgcolor="959595" align="left" style="padding: 0px;"><br>Table 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to nest the two tables within another table and apply cellpaddin="0" and cellspacing="0"

You will also need a conditional statement to make the tables stack on outlook so you can keep it responsive.

I have tested using litmus and this works fine, code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .msoFix {
            mso-table-lspace: -1pt;
            mso-table-rspace: -1pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">

                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table class="msoFix" width="320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="290" bgcolor="454545" align="left" style="padding: 0px;"><br>Table 1</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
             <![endif]-->

                                <table class="msoFix" width="320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="290" bgcolor="959595" align="left" style="padding: 0px;"><br>Table 2</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```